# Function returning wrong values

Tags: c, function, struct

I'm learning to code in C and I bumped into a problem with functions, when you input the values it gives you 0.00 + randomnumber.000000000000000000000000i
I used the same printf to try to find if something happens inside the code but the problem looks to be in the function func_complejo itself. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h> //entrada y salida

typedef struct
{
    float real, imaginario;
} complejo;

complejo func_complejo(void);
void func_mostrarComplejo(complejo complejoOut);

int main()
{
    complejo complejoAux;

    complejoAux = func_complejo();
    printf("\nEl numero ingresado es %.2f + %.2fi", &complejoAux.real, &complejoAux.imaginario);
    func_mostrarComplejo(complejoAux);

    return 0;
}

complejo func_complejo(void)
{
    complejo complejoIn;
    printf("\nIngrese la parte real de un complejo: ");
    scanf("%f", &complejoIn.real);
    printf("\nAhora ingrese la parte imaginaria de un complejo: ");
    scanf("%f", &complejoIn.imaginario);

    printf("\nEl numero ingresado es %.2f + %.2fi", &complejoIn.real, &complejoIn.imaginario);
    return complejoIn;
}

void func_mostrarComplejo(complejo complejoOut)
{
    printf("\nEl numero ingresado es %.2f + %.2fi", &complejoOut.real, &complejoOut.imaginario);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In each of your `printf` calls, you're passing a `float *` to match with a `%f` format specifier which expects a `float` or `double`.  Mismatching format specifier triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which is why you're seeing the results you do.

You don't need to pass addresses for `printf`.  The `scanf` function needs addresses so it can write to the variable in question.

These errors can be fixed by getting rid of the address-of operator in each of your `printf` calls:

```
printf("\nEl numero ingresado es %.2f + %.2fi", complejoAux.real, complejoAux.imaginario);
```